# Does the Date.UTC() method in javascript create local time zone or GMT

Tags: javascript, date, methods

Can I ask does the Date.UTC() method in javascript create local time zone or GMT??Thanks!!

Comment: Don't you think it would be a little strange for the standard API of the "Date" object to have a "UTC()" function that did *not* create a UTC timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTC should be GMT. (but do remember, in the UK summer time is not GMT)

Answer (score 0):

UTC is *[almost but not quite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)* the same as GMT.